# Downloading a public dataset from Google BigQuery using Spark to PC

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-bigquery

I would like to ask for your help. I have solved a lot of problems for this task myself but unfortunately I am not able to solve the following one. I need to download a public dataset (for example bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare) from Google BigQuery using Spark (namely PySpark) to my PC. It should be something like "HelloWorld" example for me. I have installed Spark locally in VirtualBox 6.0.10 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). First, I want to show some data from the above-mentioned table for beginning. I have created the following piece of code for that (the code is in the file called `spark_download_data_from_bq.py`).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""BigQuery I/O PySpark example."""
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from google.cloud import bigquery

spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.master('local') \
.appName('spark-bigquery-demo') \
.getOrCreate()

bucket = "gs://my-test-bucket-xxxx"
spark.conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', bucket)

# Load data from BigQuery.
df_data = spark.read.format('bigquery') \
.option("credentialsFile", "/home/user/Downloads/test-project-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.json")\
.option("parentProject", "test-project-i-xxxxxx")\
.option("project", "test-project-i-xxxxxx")\
.option('table', 'bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare') \
.load()
df_data.createOrReplaceTempView('data')
df_data.show()
```

I run it using the following command: `/home/user/Downloads/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --jars /home/user/Downloads/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11-0.13.1-beta.jar /home/user/Downloads/spark_download_data_from_bq.py`

Unfortunately, I have the following error and I do not know how to solve:

```
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.showString.
    : 
com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: request failed: the user does not have 'bigquery.readsessions.create' permission for 'projects/test-project-i-xxxxxx ...'
```

I don't know how/where to change the `bigquery.readsessions.create` property. Could you help me? Should the code work after fixing this problem? Do you have a better idea how to download data from BigQuery?

Thanks a lot.

A.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this permission in the GCP console:

- Go to the [IAM page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) (Identity and Access Management)
- Find the user you are using, and click on the edit pencil on the side
- Click on `ADD ANOTHER ROLE`
- In the role selection field, select `BigQuery Read Session User`

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. I did it as you recommended but unfortunately the problem is the same. Do you have any other idea?  I am new in this area and there are a lot of settings there.. Hence I am happy for each advice.. Should I refresh the new settings somehow or check something in linux terminal on local machine? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you grant the `BigQuery Read Session User` to the service account to which the key file in `credentialsFile` belong? The error you get now is exactly the same?

Comment: Yes. I deleted old keys in Service Accounts UI and I generated a new json file which I downloaded to the same location on my PC. I changed the row `.option("credentialsFile", "/home/user/Downloads/test-project-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.json")` and the problem is the same. Is there `.option("project", "name_of_project")` or `.option("project", "name_of_project_id")`? I used the second case but if I use `name_of_project` in the `.option("project", "name_of_project")`  then I have the following error: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: `PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on resource project test-project-i`

Comment: @Rabinowitz If my Google account is e.g. xyz123@gmail.com then the user (as you wrote in your answer) is xyz123@gmail.com? In your IAM page it is called `Member`. I hope that it is the same thing and the `user` in the error message is the same thing as well.  I would like to be only sure that I do it correctly.. because I do not know where the problem is..:-(

Comment: They are the same. If you have run `gcloud auth login` from the command line, search for the JSON file under $HOME/.config/gcloud (in one of the subdirectories). As long as you are running locally, you can also export the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/file.json`

Answer (score 1):

The “bigquery.readsessions.create” permission is used by the BigQuery Storage API. You can see the definition of the permission [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bq-permissions).

To overcome this issue you may grant your service account the bigquery.readSessionUser or the bigquer.user [roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery) or create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) which includes this permission.